# How to delay things in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, clock

```py
import kivy
from kivy.clock import Clock, mainthread
if int(value) > int(value2):
    self.ids.scoring.text = 'blue wins'
    Clock.schedule_once(2)
    self.ids.scoring.text = '0-0'
```

I run this code in Pycharm and I get this error message:

> File "kivy_clock.pyx", line 498, in kivy._clock.CyClockBase.schedule_once
> ValueError: callback must be a callable, got 2

How do i fix this?

Comment: Check your indentation, this code will not run as written.

Comment: what event you want to delay ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.clock.html

and the error message `callback must be a callable`

`Clock.schedule_once()` is waiting a `function`, not an `int`.

```
# dt means delta-time
def my_callback(dt):
    self.ids.scoring.text = 'blue wins'

# call my_callback in 5 seconds
Clock.schedule_once(my_callback, 2)
self.ids.scoring.text = '0-0'
```

Comment: yeah that works, thanks, but for def my_callback you need to pass self as well so it works, thanks for your help though